# Вывести данные из MySQL в JSON-формат (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, json

Нужно вывести данные из БД MySQL в JSON-формате такого вида:

```
{
    "response": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "first_name": "Ilya",
            "last_name": "Perekopsky",
        },
        {
            "id": 87,
            "first_name": "Ekaterina",
            "last_name": "Kalinina",
        },
        {
            "id": 2367,
            "first_name": "Nikita",
            "last_name": "Medvedkin",
        }
    ]
}
```

Опыта работы с php не было и пока удается вывести только одну запись.

Comment: Код мы должны самостоятельно представить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$query = "SELECT `id` FROM `table`";
$rows = $db->query($query);

$json = [];
while($row => $rows->fetch_assoc()) {
    $json[] = ['id' => $row['id']];
}
$return = json_encode(array('response' => $json));
var_dump($return);
?>
```